# Email sent from Google App Engine goes to Spam in Gmail

Tags: google-app-engine

We are sending newsletters to users subscribed through a TV Show website, using Google App Engine Java Mail API.

The FROM address we are using are *name@example.com* but the problem occurs with *name@[appid].appspotmail.com* as well.

We already setup a SPF and DKIM records and we have a low score on SpamAssassin (about 0.7).

All others email providers receive the email normally (hotmail, yahoo, aol, etc.), but, in Gmail, ALL messages are sent straight to Spam folder. Every single one.

Anyone have a clue on this?

Comment: If you click 'show original' on the mail in gmail, does it say dkim:pass and spf:pass (this will be somewhere near authentication-results)

Comment: @Bert Thanks for your answer!Yes it does, everything seems to be ok.


Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of zzzzzzzzzzzz@m3kw2wvrgufz5godrsrytgd7.apphosting.bounces.google.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) client-ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of zzzzzzzzzzzz@m3kw2wvrgufz5godrsrytgd7.apphosting.bounces.google.com designates xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mail=zzzzzzzzzzzz@m3kw2wvrgufz5godrsrytgd7.apphosting.bounces.google.com; dkim=pass header.i=@yyyyyyyyyy.com

Comment: Strange, what is the content of the mail?

Comment: @Bert We tryed to send just newsletters to the subscribers (HTML + text). But, on further tests, ANYTHING we send will go straight to the spam inbox in gmail, even pure text.

Answer (score 0):

If all the other mail providers are working, you may want to look at gmail's spam policy: https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126 It may shed some light on the issues you're having.

Comment: There's the strange thing...we are already following most of Gmail's spam policy.

If we send the same newsletter from other solutions (SendGrid, Amazon SES, custom installed Postfix, etc.), the email reaches almost every Gmail's inbox.

But, if we send from GAE, not every single one reach Gmail's inbox.

Comment: @user1629038 maybe look at including list-unsubscribe header https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/overview#Sending_Mail_with_Headers

Comment: last resort: log a bug. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=mail